# Ip Address Parse Problem in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am reading IPaddress from xml file and I put it into IPaddress.parse() and then use it but it does not work. it says "An invalid IP address was specified." but when I write it manually it works.

why I cant use IP address after reading xml file. I tried to erase "white spaces" , it said samething again.

```
string ipadd; //take ip address from xml and use
 ...
 IPAddress ipaddre = IPAddress.Parse(ipadd); 
------------------------------
 IPAddress ipaddre = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255")
```

why these are not giving same result?

Comment: What is the exact value of ipadd that's passed to IPAddress.Parse?

Comment: try to check what is actual value of `ipadd` in debug

Comment: I  put value of ipadd to a label, it is same , both of them are 255.255.255.255 ... but I will try to debug and return back.

Comment: I think it has \n and \r characters , it makes error . thanks everyone :)

Comment: `I think it has \n and \r characters` +1 for that! I got this "An invalid IP address was specified." error when the IP address had a dodgy hidden trailing character, probably due to copy and pasting from somewhere else. Fixed by deleting and manually typing the IP address in again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ipadd == "255.255.255.255"` then there should be nothing stopping that from working.

Obviously, though, `ipadd != "255.255.255.255"`

I would suggest debugging, setting a breakpoint, and inspecting the value of `ipadd` when you pass it to the `IPAddress.Parse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that ipadd = "255.255.255.2552", then only two possibilities exist:

1) An exception is being thrown on the parse, and therefore your compare is not happening, or 
2) The method you are using to compare the two results is not appropriate.

I strongly suggest you add both statements and place a breakpoint on the next line, then you will see exactly what you are dealing with:

```
IPAddress ipaddreReal = IPAddress.Parse(ipadd);
IPAddress ipaddreFake = IPAddress.Parse("255.255.255.255");
bool result = ipAddre.Real.Equals(ipaddreFake);
```